# Excel Graphs - Exclude someone who is off

Tags: excel, graph

I have data, in two separate columns, that shows people and how many products they have sold in the previous day:

```
Alan        12 
Gareth      7 
Kristina    8 
Fred        Off 
Emma        7
```

What I would like to do is not include Fred in the graph as he was off for that day.  Is there an easy way to exclude someone if they were "off"?

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: Hi There , please provide further details like range of cells which have data is "12" mentioned in next col or the same Col

Comment: They are both separate columns sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add a filter in those columns. Now filter the column to remove the value Off. The graph will be updated automatically.

Comment: That is NOTHING short of simple yet genius.  Thank you :)